# Is C++11 available in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017

I am currently using Visual Studio Community 2017. From looking at the C++ Language Standards in the project properties, they only provide C++14 and C++17. Since my code was completed for a previous assignment using a compiler for C++11, I am unable to run my code using functions such as stoi. My question is if there is a way to add C++11 to the language standards for C++?

I am creating a DLL for a GUI, my initializations are:

```
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
```

Here I am creating a fraction class, the main errors follow in the ifstream:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& f) {

string number;
in >> number;                           //read the number

size_t delimiter = number.find("/");    //find the delimiter in the string "/"

if (delimiter != string::npos) {            //if delimiter is not empty

    int n = stoi(number.substr(0, delimiter));      //set numerator from string to integer before the "/"
    int d = stoi(number.substr(delimiter + 1));     //set denominator from string to integer after the "/"

    if (d == 0) { //if denominator is 0
        throw FractionException("Illegal denominator, cannot divide by zero.");  //illegal argument throw
    }
    else if (n == 0 && d != 0) {    //numerator is 0, then set values as zero fraction
        f.numVal = 0;
        f.denVal = 1;
    }
    else {                      //set the values into the fraction and normalize and reduce fraction to minimum
        f.numVal = n;
        f.denVal = d;

        f.normalizeAndReduce(f.numVal, f.denVal);
    }
}
else {  //else if there is no delimiter it would be a single integer
    f.numVal = stoi(number);
    f.denVal = 1;
}

return in;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
C2679: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operator of type 'std::string"
C3861: 'stoi' identifier not found
```

This method worked perfectly fine in eclipse, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: C++11 is default (that is there is no flag to disable implemented C++11 features). See [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance).

Comment: VS2017 is almost fully compliant with C++11, including stoi (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/string-functions#stoi) maybe if you show the problem code we could help.

Comment: @zdan I added the problem code, thanks for the help!

Comment: You forgot to `#include` both `<string>` and `<iostream>`, haven't you?

Comment: @sam the iostream is in my header file and it is included in the "stdafx.h"

Comment: stdafx.h is microsoft's name for a precompiled header (the name dates back from their dark era where AFX was a flagship product, which became MFC, which became a dead thing). Anyhow, if you include that header, make it first.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Visual C++ 2017 compiler is C++11/C++14 compliant with a few specific exceptions:

- [Expression SFINAE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/sfinae-update/) is implemented, but not complete. (*Now complete in VS 2017 (15.7)*)
- Full C99 preprocessor support is limited due to some bugs with variadic macros
- Two phase name lookup is in VS 2017 (15.3 update) but is [incomplete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) and only active when using [/permissive-](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) (*Now complete in VS 2017 (15.7)*)

The compiler does not offer a specific C++11 mode and defaults to C++14, but that standard is fully inclusive of C++11. C++17 support is in progress, and requires you use the [/std:c++17](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) or `/std::c++latest` switch.

`std::stoi` requires you include the appropriate header, specifically `<string>>` Either you forgot to include that header -or- you didn't deal with the `namespace` resolution (either explicitly as `std::` or via `using namespace std;`)

> See [C++17 Features And STL Fixes In VS 2017 15.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/11/c17-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-2017-15-3/) for the latest status of C++11/C++14/C++17 standards conformance as of the VS 2017 (15.3 update)

**UPDATED:** For the latest on Visual C++ conformance, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance).

Now that you have posted your code, I see that the problem has *nothing* to do with which standard is supported. Your problem is that you don't know the secrets of how Precompiled Headers work.

Change:

```
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
```

to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
```

-or- add `#include <string>` to the precompiled header `stdafx.h` directly.

See [Creating Precompiled Header Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-precompiled-header-files)

Comment: Compiler defaults to C++11 (actually it was a bit messy until switches were introduced). In order to use C++14 `/std:c++14` flag should be used. See [Standards version switches in the compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/).

Comment: @VTT: Please re-read your link more thoroughly, they specifically say that C++14 corresponds to the language level when the switches were introduced, and there will be no C__11 mode.

Comment: @chuck So it is an available compiler! I do have both
#include <string>
using namespace std;
However, I am getting the following error code:
C3861 'stoi':identifier not found

Comment: I don't know what else your code is doing or is formatted as, but this function works just fine in the VS 2017 compiler

Comment: @VTT The Visual C++ team didn't feel there was much value in having a distinct C++14 vs. C++11 mode. C++14 is really just some bug fixes for C++11 plus a few improvements to make use of C++11 constructs more general. In addition to enabling new C++17 constructs, the ``/std::c++17`` switch also has the effect of removing some Standard Library things that were deprecated in C++14 so it's potentially a bigger impact on code. Also, a few C++14 things were already in VS 2013 so it wasn't quite as a cleanly separated from C++11.

Comment: @user3344484: you should post a question specifically about your `stoi()` problem.  including a **minimal**, complete example that still causes the problem and include the compiler command line use to build the program (and produces the error). Note that even when using the IDE to build you can find the command line used to compile in the "CL.command.1.tlog" file in the build's output directory.

Comment: Updated the code for the method where I am getting errors

Comment: @chuck Welp that rearrangement literally solved my problem...thanks!

Comment: Yup. When precompiled headers are being used, anything *before* the PCH headers is included is ignored in all the source file *except* the one that's used to generate the PCH (which is ``stdafx.cpp`` by default in the VS templates). It was like your ``#include <string>`` wasn't there... Another fix here would have been to disable PCH usage for the entire project or even just your one source file.

Comment: I hate the VS defaults to using pre-compiled headers.  Let people turn them on if/when compile time is a problem.

Comment: Precompiled headers in the Win32 console app template is indeed silly. It does, however make a lot of difference for Win32 windows apps because ``#include <windows.h>`` alone pulls in a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft I think has declared that

> Note that there is no plan to add a C++11 switch. [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/)

So there's not an explicit switch

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this, VS 2017, Update 9.4 (releasd Dec 2018) is now fully C++17 compliant.

Comment: OP's question is regarding C++11 compliance.

Answer (score -7):

C++ is an evolving standard - after 2003 there was 2011 (C++11) then 2014 (C++14) and now we have 2017 (C++17) and we're working towards 2020 (C++20).  They're upward compatible.

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) for Microsoft Visual C++ support for the various standards.