# How to Change C++ standards in VS 2017?

Tags: c++

I want to test a Visual studio project for C++ 03 standards.
I have Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and my C++ console application compiles fine.

What settings should I change in Visual studio 2017 so that the C++ compiler doesn't use the latest C++ versions but say "switches to" the C++ 03 standards ?

(What I aiming is, later as a Proof of Concept, I need to copy this source files into a Linux box 'makefile project'. The linux box doesn't conform to C++11 standards. So I need to test the working)

Comment: Related/duoe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043869/is-c11-available-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: What version of GCC/Clang are you stick with so you don't have C++11 or higher? I wouldn't downgrade visual studio, I'd rather invest time to upgrade your Linux compilers

Comment: That's a decision my organization has to make. I am new to linux but had been a VS programmer all along.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio doesn't support this.  Your options are C++latest, C++17, and C++14.  C++17 mode is fairly well conforming, and C++14 mode is close.

Further reading on learn.microsoft.com: [/std (Specify Language Standard Version)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Yes I am aware of the /set option. It enables the settings. I didn't see an option to disable.  Guess there is no such feature in VS. Thanks for the response.

Comment: /std:c++latest disables conformance.  But this means turning everything on (including features that won't be available until C++20).  If you're looking to validate that code built on Windows will also build on Linux, you might consider Clang for Windows.  Its -std=C++98 option isn't perfect but should reduce the chance of cross-compiler issues.  There's also mingw.